# Kivy 2 lines of text for label

Tags: python, kivy, label

```
<AI_Window>:
name: "AI"

GridLayout:
    cols:1
    rows:4

    Label:
        text: "Data Mining "
        text: "test"
```

I am trying to assign 2 lines of text for the Label. However when i run this, the output is "test" instead of  "test" and "Data Mining ".

Is there a way to output both "test" and "Data Mining" on the label?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text: "Data Mining\\ntest"
```

Comment: the output is Data Mining\ntest

Comment: i figured it out, only one "\" suppose to use, thanks tho